# Download image to internal storage

Tags: android

I want to download an image from url and save to Internal Storage
I have this code but if my phone do not have External Storage the image can not to be download

```
    Bitmap b=null;
    URL url;
    InputStream iStream=null;
    File tmpFile;
    try {
        url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();            
        urlConnection.connect();
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        File cacheDirectory = context.getCacheDir();
        tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/news.png");
        FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);

        fOutStream.flush();
        fOutStream.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {

    }
    return b;
```

do you help me to download image from url to Internal Storage insted of External Storage

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to check that whether the phone has external directory or not. The [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) already has the code to do it.

```
/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to download image to Internal Storage(my device don't have External Storage)

Comment: Try doing this `tmpFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "news.png");` or see this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage) and according to documentation getCacheDir returns internal storage... for information on how to save files in internal storage see this tutorial [link](http://codetheory.in/android-saving-files-on-internal-and-external-storage/)

Comment: whats wrong with your code, does it crash, or prints some error in logcat?